# Why do I get an error that says: missing ; before statement?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log "january".substring(0,3);
console.log "melbourne is great".substring(0,12);
console.log "hamburgers".substring(4,10);
```

i am trying to understand why this won't work?

Comment: If you do not like parentheses around function parameters have a look at CoffeeScript. Personally I think it's pretty ugly but lots of people seem to like it...

Answer (score 7):

`console.log()` is a function. JavaScript is not Ruby, parens are required :)

**Example:**

```
console.log("january".substring(0,3));
```

Comment: Hi Gavin, welcome to Stack Overflow. To make your answer even more complete, consider adding examples to your answer via an [edit]. Good luck! :)

Comment: so console.log("january".substring(0,3));

Comment: Hey people. I had this correct all the time, my only mistake was the following:  Using console.log, on three separate lines, print out the substrings for the following strings.

a. "Jan" in "January"
b. "Melbourne is" in "Melbourne is great" (note the space!)
c. "burgers" in "Hamburgers"    and I did January, Melbourne and Hamburgers with small letters. Sorry for wasting your time. I started to change the code because I thought that was the error. JavaScript doesn't tell that